# How to send a class annotated @Configuration as a REST response ? in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, serialization, jackson

I want to send this class as the response for a REST service

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
public class Test { 
private String str;
}
```

A controller has method :

```
@Autowired
private Test test;

@GetMapping("/url")
public Test config() {
    return test;
}
```

The exception I am getting is:

```
Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.beans.support.ResourceEditorRegistrar]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.beans.support.ResourceEditorRegistrar and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
```

Comment: You need a serializer for the class.. Also, return `test` and not `Test`

Comment: @DanielM Could you please give a sample code with the serializer ?